# Physics_ODE Install

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I have recently discovered that ROS has a patched ode engine.  Installing electric ROS full, revealed the patched opende engine (with the parrallel_step) library.  First I wanted to thank the programmers for this awesome patch.

I am interested in using this package outside of ROS, and it seems that the libraries are very similar if not the same as the ode packages.  Also from the documentation page, I garner that the library can be used apart from ROS.  My goal is to use this ode engine with OpenRAVE in the OpenRAVE environment (I know there is a way to use OpenRAVE in ROS, but I am still learning about that.)  So my question:

I have linked the includes, and the ode-config bin to my /usr.  (I also rebuilt the library because the ode-config bin gave out wrong --cflags and --libs).  Does anyone know if this is enough?  Does anyone have experience with what I am attempting?  Thank you so much!

Constantin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11420/physics_ode-install/) by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 296 on 2011-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's the right sort of approach.  You could also consider installing the library so your paths end up cleaner. All the source for how it is compiled is in the [physics_ode stack source](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/physics_ode/trunk/)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0